# scrapy with each item pipeline wrapped within spider file

Tags: python, import, scrapy, decorator

I use scrapy for a project with item pipeline specifically designed for items fields need to be inserted into database. I'm employing a python decorator method for this to work. For some reason I can't get my head wrapped around this issue, I get particular nameError which I am not sure where are they coming from.
Note: this method people have confirmed was working perfectly fine.

This is the code I have in my spider.py file:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request,FormRequest
from exampleScraper.items import exampleItem
import urllib, time, MySQLdb, sys

today = time.strftime("%x %X")

class idoxpaSpider(Spider):
  pipeline = set(['insert'])

  name = 'idoxpaSpider'

  start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]
  ###
  def parse(self, response):
    # some scrapy work 
    return item

###
class insert(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(<some parameters>)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

  @check_spider_pipeline
  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    return item
```

and this is what I have in my pipeline file:

```
import sys

class BoroughscrperPipeline(object):
  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    def check_spider_pipeline(process_item_method):
      @functools.wraps(process_item_method)
      def wrapper(self, item, spider):
      # message template for debugging
        msg = '%%s %s pipeline step' % (self.__class__.__name__,)

        # if class is in the spider pipeline then use use process_item normally
        if self.__class__ in spider.pipeline:
          spider.log(msg % 'executing', level=log.DEBUG)
          return process_item_method(self, item, spider)

      # otherwise return the untouched item
        else:
          spider.log(msg % 'skipping', level=log.DEBUG)
          return item
      return wrapper
```

and this is the acutal error I am getting:

```
File "/home/mn/workbench/boroughScrper/boroughScrper/spiders/westminsterSpider.py", line 40, in insert
    @check_spider_pipeline
NameError: name 'check_spider_pipeline' is not defined
```

Any idea where is this going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `check_spider_pipeline` is "not defined" because it can't be found. It is not in the scope visible to your `spider.py` script, but defined in the locals of `BoroughscrperPipeline.process_item`. You need to make it visible in your scope. Check this answer for example: [How can I use different pipelines for different spiders in a single Scrapy project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372703/how-can-i-use-different-pipelines-for-different-spiders-in-a-single-scrapy-proje)