# How to use a decorator to enable a spider to distinguish between scrapy pipelines

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, scrapy, twisted

I've made a scrapy project that contains multiple spiders in a file and need the interpreter to be able distinguish which pipeline is associated with which spider, similar to the person who asked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372703/how-can-i-use-different-pipelines-for-different-spiders-in-a-single-scrapy-project). Using the solution provided by the top voted answer, I put the decorator within the pipeline classes and then defined the pipelines lists within the spiders themselves. But when I run this, I get a name error because the pipelines are defined in the spider file.

Since the pipelines.py file isn't a module you can't really import it into the spiders.py file. I'm not sure if the answer posted is still relevant since its not recent, but it seems like it did work properly for someone so it is worth a try at least. Btw, I'm running the two spiders I have sequentially based on the code provided in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) and even though both spiders run when I use the command: scrapy runspider, I think the pipeline classes are not being called. However, when I run each spider individually, the tables are filled properly. I also included both pipeline classes in the settings.py dicionary. So from this, I have a few questions:

**[1.]** Do I have the correct set up of both files based on the answer that was provided in the question?
**[2.]** If so, how would I properly connect the namespaces of the two files?

**[3.]** Is there a better way to do this besides just creating separate projects?

I have the code for both files below, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**pipelines.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Tickets, Tickets3, db_connect, create_vs_tickets_table, create_tc_tickets_table



class ComparatorPipeline(object):
    """Price comparison pipeline for storing scraped items in the database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_vs_tickets_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save tickets in the database.

        This method is called for every item pipeline component.

        """

        def check_spider_pipeline(process_item_method):

                @functools.wraps(process_item_method)
                def wrapper(self, item, spider):
                    #message template for debugging
                    msg = '%%s %s pipeline step' % (self.__.class__.__name__,)

                    #if class is in the spider's pipeline, then use the 
                    #process_item method normally.
                    if self.__class__ in spider.pipeline:
                        spider.log(msg % 'executing', level=log.DEBUG)
                        return process_item_method(self, item, spider)

                    #otherwise, just return the untouched item (skip this step in the pipeline)
                else:
                    spider.log(msg % 'skipping', level= log.DEBUG)
                    return item
                return wrapper  
            if spider.name == "comparator":
            session = self.Session()
            ticket = Tickets(**item)

            try:
                session.add(ticket)
                session.commit()
            except:
                session.rollback()
                raise
            finally:
                session.close()

            return item

class ComparatorPipeline2(object):
    """Price comparison pipeline for storing scraped items in the database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_tc_tickets_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save tickets in the database.

        This method is called for every item pipeline component.

        """
        def check_spider_pipeline(process_item_method):

            @functools.wraps(process_item_method)
            def wrapper(self, item, spider):
                #message template for debugging
                msg = '%%s %s pipeline step' % (self.__.class__.__name__,)

                #if class is in the spider's pipeline, then use the 
                #process_item method normally.
                if self.__class__ in spider.pipeline:
                    spider.log(msg % 'executing', level=log.DEBUG)
                    return process_item_method(self, item, spider)

                #otherwise, just return the untouched item (skip this step in the pipeline)
            else:
                spider.log(msg % 'skipping', level= log.DEBUG)
                return item
            return wrapper  

        if spider.name == "comparator2":
            session = self.Session()
            ticket2 = Tickets2(**item)

            try:
                session.add(ticket2)
                session.commit()
            except:
                session.rollback()
                raise
            finally:
                session.close()

            return item
```

**spider class definitions**

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from concert_comparator.items import ComparatorItem, ComparatorItem3
from urlparse import urljoin

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

bandname = raw_input("Enter a bandname \n")

vs_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"
tc_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    pipeline = set([
        ComparatorPipeline
        ])
    pipeline = ['first']
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.vividseats.com"]
    start_urls = [vs_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'

    def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('tickets')
        price_list = [i.get('p') for i in ticket_info]
        if len(price_list) > 0:
            str_Price = str(price_list[0])
            ticketPrice = unicode(str_Price, "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        else:
            ticketPrice = unicode("sold out", "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()
    def parse_price(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"(\d+)[^-]*$", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=" + json_id
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/*/a[@class = "btn btn-primary"]/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , './/*[@class = "productionsDate"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
            ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)


class MySpider3(CrawlSpider):
    pipeline = set([
        ComparatorPipeline2
        ])
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator3'
    allowed_domains = ["www.ticketcity.com"]
    start_urls = [tc_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/div[@class = "vevent"]'

    def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('B')
        price_list = [i.get('P') for i in ticket_info]
        if len(price_list) > 0:
            str_Price = str(price_list[0])
            ticketPrice = unicode(str_Price, "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        else:
            ticketPrice = unicode("sold out", "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price(self, response):
        print "parse price function entered \n"
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        event_City = response.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract() 
        eventCity = ''.join(event_City) 
        loader.add_value('eventCity' , eventCity)
        event_State = response.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text()').extract() 
        eventState = ''.join(event_State) 
        loader.add_value('eventState' , eventState) 
        event_Date = response.xpath('.//span[@class="event_datetime"]/text()').extract() 
        eventDate = ''.join(event_Date)  
        loader.add_value('eventDate' , eventDate)    
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"(\d+)[^-]*$", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/Catalog/public/v1/events/" + json_id + "/ticketblocks?P=0,99999999&q=0&per_page=250&page=1&sort=p.asc&f.t=s&_=1436642392938"
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/span[@class="summary listingEventName"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/div[@class="divVenue location"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/a[@class="divEventDetails url"]/@href')
            #loader.add_xpath('eventDateTime' , '//div[@id="divEventDate"]/@title') #datetime type
            #loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
            ticketsURL = "https://www.ticketcity.com/" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)


configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider)
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider3)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

[image: pipelines directory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really at least read about decorators and how they are used before posting this type of question.

You don't have them set up properly. You should create 1 project with at least 2 modules. One module named spiders and another named pipelines. Note that for a directory to be considered a module it needs to have a file named __init__.py in it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/2368836

In your pipelines module add a file called util with the following code:

```
def check_spider_pipeline(process_item_method):
    """
        This wrapper makes it so pipelines can be turned on and off at a spider level.
    """
    @functools.wraps(process_item_method)
    def wrapper(self, item, spider):
        msg = '%%s %s pipeline step' % (self.__class__.__name__,)
        if self.__class__ in spider.pipeline:
            spider.log(msg % 'executing', level=log.DEBUG)
            return process_item_method(self, item, spider)
        else:
            spider.log(msg % 'skipping', level=log.DEBUG)
            return item

    return wrapper
```

Create another file in pipelines called pipelines:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Tickets, Tickets3, db_connect, create_vs_tickets_table, create_tc_tickets_table
from pipelines.util import check_spider_pipeline


class ComparatorPipeline(object):
    """Price comparison pipeline for storing scraped items in the database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_vs_tickets_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    @check_spider_pipeline    
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save tickets in the database.

        This method is called for every item pipeline component.

        """

            if spider.name == "comparator":
            session = self.Session()
            ticket = Tickets(**item)

            try:
                session.add(ticket)
                session.commit()
            except:
                session.rollback()
                raise
            finally:
                session.close()

            return item

class ComparatorPipeline2(object):
    """Price comparison pipeline for storing scraped items in the database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_tc_tickets_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    @check_spider_pipeline    
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save tickets in the database.

        This method is called for every item pipeline component.

        """ 

        if spider.name == "comparator2":
            session = self.Session()
            ticket2 = Tickets2(**item)

            try:
                session.add(ticket2)
                session.commit()
            except:
                session.rollback()
                raise
            finally:
                session.close()

            return item
```

in spiders module:

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from concert_comparator.items import ComparatorItem, ComparatorItem3
from urlparse import urljoin

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from pipelines.pipelines import ComparatorPipeline, ComparatorPipeline2

bandname = raw_input("Enter a bandname \n")

vs_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"
tc_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    pipeline = set([
        ComparatorPipeline
        ])
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.vividseats.com"]
    start_urls = [vs_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'

    def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('tickets')
        price_list = [i.get('p') for i in ticket_info]
        if len(price_list) > 0:
            str_Price = str(price_list[0])
            ticketPrice = unicode(str_Price, "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        else:
            ticketPrice = unicode("sold out", "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()
    def parse_price(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"(\d+)[^-]*$", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=" + json_id
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/*/a[@class = "btn btn-primary"]/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , './/*[@class = "productionsDate"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
            ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)


class MySpider3(CrawlSpider):
    pipeline = set([
        ComparatorPipeline2
        ])
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator3'
    allowed_domains = ["www.ticketcity.com"]
    start_urls = [tc_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/div[@class = "vevent"]'

    def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('B')
        price_list = [i.get('P') for i in ticket_info]
        if len(price_list) > 0:
            str_Price = str(price_list[0])
            ticketPrice = unicode(str_Price, "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        else:
            ticketPrice = unicode("sold out", "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price(self, response):
        print "parse price function entered \n"
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        event_City = response.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract() 
        eventCity = ''.join(event_City) 
        loader.add_value('eventCity' , eventCity)
        event_State = response.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text()').extract() 
        eventState = ''.join(event_State) 
        loader.add_value('eventState' , eventState) 
        event_Date = response.xpath('.//span[@class="event_datetime"]/text()').extract() 
        eventDate = ''.join(event_Date)  
        loader.add_value('eventDate' , eventDate)    
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"(\d+)[^-]*$", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/Catalog/public/v1/events/" + json_id + "/ticketblocks?P=0,99999999&q=0&per_page=250&page=1&sort=p.asc&f.t=s&_=1436642392938"
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/span[@class="summary listingEventName"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/div[@class="divVenue location"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/a[@class="divEventDetails url"]/@href')
            #loader.add_xpath('eventDateTime' , '//div[@id="divEventDate"]/@title') #datetime type
            #loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
            ticketsURL = "https://www.ticketcity.com/" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner()

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def crawl():
        yield runner.crawl(MySpider)
        yield runner.crawl(MySpider3)
        reactor.stop()

    crawl()
    reactor.run()
```

Also make sure you have these pipelines defined in settings. And I also recommend using scrapy crawl spider_name over the code at the bottom of your spiders file until you have this stuff all figured out.

Project structure example:

[image]

NOTE: I did not make sure this worked with the stuff about getting a band name from the user. If you want to do that you are much better off doing something similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15618520/2368836

Comment: Even when the pipelines.py file is put inside of the pipelines folder (which is in the same directory as the spiders folder), it can't be imported into the module with the spiders because they aren't in the same directory. I think it might just be better to put each spider in its own project. Thanks for the code btw

Comment: I don't agree that using separate projects would be better. I forgot to mention this in the answer but you need to make sure each directory that is treated as a module has a file named \_\_init\_\_.py. This is enables python to treat the directory as an importable module..

http://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/2368836

Comment: The problem with using separate projects is that you will easily end up with duplicated code and it will get much harder to manage.

Comment: I had already put the __init__.py inside of the pipelines folder, but I was still getting the error that concert_comparator.pipelines doesn't define object ComparatorPipeline. I think it might have been because Scrapy checks the directory directly above the spiders folder for the pipelines.py or something, not exactly sure. But right now, I'm just  trying to run the spiders from a bash script.

Comment: have you tried from pipelines.pipelines import ComparatorPipeline? If your directory structure is like the image I posted it should work. I have a project with 20+ pipelines and over 50 spiders.

Comment: I used all of the imports that were posted. I just made an edit to the post with a screen shot of my directory.

Comment: Weird. If you have the init files in pipelines and spiders it seems like it should work. Not sure what is wrong. If you figure it out let me know because the setup you have seems to work for me. When importing you don't need to include the project name btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83370/discussion-between-loremipsum1771-and-rocktheartsm4l).