# How to raise scrapy.exceptions.DropItem in scrapy_redis.pipelines.RedisPipeline

Tags: python, redis, scrapy

I have a scrapy project where I need to store some scraped items in Redis.

I was thinking about writing my own pipeline class, but then I found [scrapy-redis](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-redis) and decided to try it.

My question is: what should I do if the scraped item is *invalid*?

By *invalid*, I mean that as far as my application is concerned, this item should be discarded and not processed.

I know that if I write my own pipeline class, I can raise a `DropItem` exception, but what can I do if I use `RedisPipeline`?

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Subclass `RedisPipeline`, override `process_item`, drop an invalid
   item, and  delegate the processing of a valid item to
   `RedisPipeline.process_item`. Then use this subclassed pipeline in my spiders.
2. Define another pipeline class responsible for dropping invalid items, and give this pipeline a higher priority.

I was thinking about something along these lines:

```
class DropItemPipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if not item["is_valid"]:
        raise DropItem
    else:
        return item
```

See also: [How can I use different pipelines for different spiders in a single Scrapy project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372703/how-can-i-use-different-pipelines-for-different-spiders-in-a-single-scrapy-proje#34647090)

Comment: you can have multiple pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up multiple pipelines for your project, so you can use ScrapyRedis pipeline with the one you write for dropping items:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'my.own.Pipeline': 299,
    'scrapy_redis.pipelines.RedisPipeline': 300,
}
```

On your own pipeline just drop the items. Check that the previous pipeline should have a lower priority (`299` in my example) than RedisPipeline, so when the items gets dropped it never reaches the following pipelines.